# Passing parameter to controller via Route::controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How can I pass a parameter via `Route::controller` to a controller?
I want to pass a parameter `user_id` to `getCreate` method in my controller

```
Route::controller('account', 'ReportController', array(
        'getCreate' => 'client.account.create',
        'postStore' => 'client.account.store',
    ));
```

Controller

```
public function getCreate($user_id = null)
{
    // need to do something here with $user_id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call your url with the user id

```
www.mydomain.com/account/create/1
```

Comment: Thanks - I was making mistake in my controller which was redirecting me to the create account page as if `user_id` is null